# Dealing with empty regions of data in a histogram

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 arrays of shape (1,N) which are right ascension and declination. The scatter plot of that data is [image]

As you can see in the top-left, data was not collected in this region and so is empty.

I would like to form the histogram of this data as a method of investigating data clustering. That empty spot (and many others like it), it seems to me, will cause a problem -- when numpy.histogram2d draws a grid on this data and begins counting data points in the cells, it will see cells that fall on the empty region and determine that there is no data there; hence the cell histogram value is zero. This pulls down the mean of the whole histogram. Having a sensible mean is important because I identify clusters via their standard deviation from the mean.

The problem is, of course, *not* that those cells are empty, but that there is *no data* to count; ideally those cells should be ignored.

Comment: Maybe you can fill in the missing values using the mean value from the remaining data?

Comment: Would writing a `nan` into those bins and then using `numpy.nanmean` be an option?